# Control techniques for linearized systems (I.E. a linearized DC-DC boost converter)

Tags: control-theory, power-electronics

I have a linearized model of a DC-DC boost converter, in matrix form:

$x' = Ax + bu + d$

(the two "x" states are the input inductor current, and the output capacitor voltage)

For controlling the output voltage, I have used:

- Cascaded PI controller (PI controller for the inner current loop, and another PI controller for the outer voltage loop)
- LQR theory

--> What other practical control methods could I use here?

Comment: Why would you want to use a third control method? What is lacking in the first two?